# Not able to create observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Calling `init` function from another class, `console.log` is never called. Later, calling `broadcast` gives the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of
>   undefined

File with observable code:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import Deferred from './Deferred';

import * as m from '../Models/models';

let sharedServiceInstance = null;

export default class SharedService {
    observable: Observable<any>;
    observer: Observer<any>;

    constructor() {
        if(!sharedServiceInstance){
            sharedServiceInstance = this;
        }
        return sharedServiceInstance;
    }

    init = () =>{
        var deferred = new Deferred<any>();
        if(this.observable != undefined){
            deferred.resolve();
        }
        else{
            this.observable = Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => {
                this.observer = observer;
                console.log("Observer: " + JSON.stringify(this.observer,null,4));
                deferred.resolve();
            }).share();
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    broadcast(event: m.SharedEventModel) {
        this.observer.next(event);
    }

    on(eventName, callback) {
        return this.observable.filter((event) => {
            return event.Name === eventName;
        }).subscribe(callback);
    }
}
```

File where observable is initiated and called:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import SharedService from '../Services/sharedService';

import * as m from '../Models/models';

let initializeServiceInstance;

export default class InitializeService {
    private sharedService = new SharedService();    

    public constructor(){
        if(!initializeServiceInstance){
            this.initialize();
            initializeServiceInstance = this;
        }
        return initializeServiceInstance;
    }

    initialize =() =>{
        var promise1 = this.sharedService.init()
        .then(()=>{
           //Debugger never reaches here
        })
        .catch((response)=>{
            //Debugger never reaches here

            var event = new m.SharedEventModel({
                Name: m.EventSubjectEnum.AfterLogout
            })
            this.sharedService.broadcast(event);
        })
    }

}
```

**NOTE:** Using `rxjs` without `angular`.

Answer (score 1):

In this block of code:

```
this.observable = Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => {
    this.observer = observer;
    console.log("Observer: " + JSON.stringify(this.observer,null,4));
}).share();
```

That inner function is not executed until there's a subscription. The only place subscriptions are happening is in `.on`, and `.on` is never called. So if there are no subscriptions yet, then this.observer will be undefined. Since it can be undefined, `this.observer.next(event);` can throw an error.

Also, if there are ever two subscriptions, then the second subscription will overwrite `this.observer`, thus making it so the first subscription will not get any notifications.

I think for what you're trying to do, you'll want to use a subject.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
// and other imports

export default class SharedService {
    subject: Subject<any>

    constructor() {
        if(!sharedServiceInstance){
            sharedServiceInstance = this;
        }
        return sharedServiceInstance;
    }

    init = () => {
        this.subject = new Subject();
    }

    broadcast(event: m.SharedEventModel) {
        this.subject.next(event);
    }

    // I don't recommend mixing callbacks and observables in this way
    on(eventName, callback) {
        return this.subject.filter((event) => {
            return event.Name === eventName;
        }).subscribe(callback);
    }

    // My recomendation would be to just return the observable
    //   That way the caller can decide whether they want to subscribe
    //   Or whether they want to do additional manipulation of the stream
    //on(eventName) {
    //    return this.subject.filter((event) => {
    //        return event.Name === eventName;
    //    });
    //}
}
```